# AppScript GoogleSheets Me gustaría unir un rango en una sola celda separada por coma

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me gustarías lograr esto en una sola celda de google sheets.
La columna A tiene 3 filas con los valores 1 2 3 y la columna B L L L
Objetivo:  ------> 1-L,2-L,3-L

cuando ejecuto el código el for solo me llama  1-L

Este es el código que estoy utilizando.

```
function ATest(){ 

var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("M");

var T = formulario.getRange("a1:b3").getValues();

var juntar = []    
for(var i = 0; i < T.length;i++){     
var unido = T[i][0]+"-"+ T[i][1];

juntar.push(unido);

formulario.getRange("D1").setValue(juntar)
  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con este script vas a poder asignar el valor de la union (1-L,2-L,3-L) en la columna D1

```
function ATest(){ 

    var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("M");
    var T = formulario.getRange("a1:b3").getValues();
    var juntar = []   

    for(var i = 0; i < T.length;i++){     
        var unido = T[i][0]+"-"+ T[i][1];
        juntar.push(unido);
        fil= i+1;  // indice más uno
        formulario.getRange("E"+fil).setValue(unido)  // concatenar 
  letra columna + nro fila

    }
    let juntartxt = juntar.join(',')
    console.log( juntartxt );
    formulario.getRange("D1").setValue(  juntartxt )

}
```